# BulkSynchronize remove subset data VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-extensions

I am using Entity Framework Extensions (EFE) in VB.Net project and I wanna to know how to write below mentioned C# Syntax in VB.Any help is appreciated

ctx.BulkSynchronize(list, options => options.ColumnSynchronizeDeleteKeySubsetExpression = c  => c.Type)

Comment: Did you try using a code converter? The code is using what's called _lambda expressions_. Look them up in C# and then check the VB.NET equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with VB.NET

```
context.BulkMerge(customers, New Action(Of Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EntityBulkOperation(Of Customer))(Sub(bulk As Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EntityBulkOperation(Of Customer))
          bulk.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = Function(cust As Customer) cust.Code
      End Sub))
```